# Style views passed to custom view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

What I would like to be able to do is use a custom `View` like this: The number or types of views passed to `Nav` can be different.

```
Nav(
    width: 200
) {
    NavButton("Item 1", action: {self.someAction}, isActive: true)
    NavButton("Item 1", action: {self.someAction}, isActive: false)
    NavTitle("Page 1")
}
```

And that it would give the same result as:

```
HStack {
    NavButton("Item 1", action: {self.someAction}, isActive: true)
    .frame(width: 200 / 3)
    NavButton("Item 1", action: {self.someAction}, isActive: false)
    .frame(width: 200 / 3)
    NavTitle("Page 1")
    .frame(width: 200 / 3)
}
```

The idea is to have evenly spaced items in a navbar.

I thought about using an array of views and passing it as a property, but that looks awful to me. Is there a way to do the same as in my example above, or any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using Spacer() between?

Comment: What would happen if the first element would have a longer label than the third? I think the middle element would then not be in the center, but slightly to the right?

Comment: So in that case you have to provide the width and height of the label and .lineLimit(nil) to get the proper response. Like the below answer

Comment: And how do I apply that elements' width and height to every element in the custom view without specifying it for every element?

Comment: You have to create a separate class for that with height and width and just call it

Comment: Check the below example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like This :-

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {


    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            CustomText(text: "kjahsfgdi f")
            Spacer()
            CustomText(text: "abc")
            Spacer()
            CustomText(text: "abc")
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CustomText : View{
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .frame(width: 100, height: nil, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```